# How to remove the hyperLink for Case Owner field in an inline VF page?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Lets say i have an inline VF page

Code Snippet

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tempList}" var="c" width="100%" columns="11">
    <apex:column value="{!c.OwnerId}" headerValue="Case Owner">
    </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlocktable>
</apex:page>
```

From the contrioller i get the tempList (List created on Case).

Now in the inline VF page i want to remove the hyper link for the case owner name that got displayed in my page.

Any Thoughts ?

Comment: You can use JavaScript for DOM manipulation for removing the links.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <apex:column value="{!c.Owner.Name}" headerValue="Case Owner" />
```